# 'Connection not found' error thrown at end of task, after the package has successfully used the connection it refers to as missing

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, visual-studio-2012

Sorry for the long title and this long question!

I'll set the scene. I'm fairly new to VS and SSIS.

I have created several SSIS packages, basically a package for retrieving data and creating a csv file, `getCSV.dtsx`, and another to Load said csv file into our Oracle tables, `loadData.dtsx`.

Now that they are working independently, I have started to put them together in one 'main' package `getandLoad_AllTables.dtsx` consisting of a sequence container for each table, 2 packages per container; getData/loadData using 'Execute Package Tasks' to call these packages from the local file system in the order I have laid out in my control flow.

The issue - both the tasks are called, run and completed within the first container however the `getandLoad_AllTables` package errors out, detailing that

`Error: 0xC001000E at loadData: The connection "{long-ass string}" is not found"`

I checked the ID of the connection in the XML of `loadData.dtsx` and found it is the main connection used within all the 'Execute SQL Tasks' in the `loadData` package, all of which ran successfully and loaded the data into the tables as expected.

Why is this error thrown in the `getandLoad_AllTables` package and not in the `loadData` package it says the connection is missing from? I am completely stumped.

Thank you in advance for any help/guidance/advice anyone can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out and documenting here in case anyone comes across this question with the same issue.

Within the `Execute Package Task Editor` I had chosen the `Reference Type` as `External Reference` and was linking to the `.dtsx` file within the file system. It seems that this option, when run directly from Visual Studio at least, wasn't cleaning up properly.

To fix, I changed the `Reference Type` to `Project Reference` and choose the required package from the list of package within the project. This ran 100%.

I have gone as far as setting this up on management studio, but to run from within Visual Studio, this fixed the issue.